# Unlink Tempfile when the path is known in Ruby

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

If I have the path of a Tempfile, how can I unlink it?

I know that if I have the tempfile itself (the object), I can call to:

`tmp_file.unlink`.

But what if I just have the path, and I want to unlink it if it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd usually use [`File.unlink`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-unlink) to unlink a file by name:

```
File.unlink(path_to_the_temp_file)
```

That will raise an `Errno::ENOENT` exception if the file doesn't exist. You can check existence before unlinking (see [`File.exist?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-exist-3F) and friends) or rescue and ignore that exception. Or you could go with [`FileUtils.remove_file`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-remove_file) and use the second parameter to ignore the exceptions:

```
require 'fileutils'
FileUtils.remove_file(path_to_temp_file, true)
```